# How to allow apache to access another directory ouside /html/www/

Tags: apache2, directory

At the moment I have a apache web server and in this web server I have a "test.html" file. this file streams an audio file from the following directory.  "audio/monkey.mp3". (full path /var/www/html/work/audio/monkey.mp3) this works fine at the moment.

ideally I would like to access another audio file in another directory, which is outside the webserver directory. for exmaple /var/spool/music/.

i tried pointing the "test.html" file to there but it didnt work. anything out side /var/www/html/ will not work.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong.. It is not ideal to point, change or modify outside the `/html/www` if the server is facing public internet as this may cause security threats. Even if it is an internal server, it is still the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache is limited to serving files within its document root. You could change the document root (probably not the best idea in this case). You could also create a symbolic link to the directory:

```
ln -s /var/spool/music /var/www/music
```

You will also need to make sure that apache has +r privileges for the files in question and +x for the directory. One way to ensure that is to change the group of the files/folder in question to `www-data`.

Answer (score 0):

I will give this a go. Is there any security risks if I use a symbolic link? the end goal is to let users be able to stream music on a web gui.

shanika